# Is it possible to exclude multiple categories in JUnit 4?

Tags: java, junit4

I would like to do something like:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(Small.class)
@Categories.ExcludeCategory({Manual.class, NonFunctional.class})
@Suite.SuiteClasses(AllTests.class)
public class SmallTests {
}
```

but ExcludeCategories accepts only one class, not an array of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [runtime-suite](https://github.com/dhemery/runtime-suite) may provide another workaround/solution.

Answer (score 3):

This will be supported in JUnit 4.12 version, see https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.java

Comment: Yeah, I did the bulk of the implementation with lots of good code review feedback from the JUnit maintainers :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a JUnit 4 feature request for this:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/146

This link also suggests a workaround:

> There is a not-so-beatiful workaround. You can get multiple includes or excludes
>   if you create an inheritance hierarchy of suites and exclude one category on
>   each level.

Comment: I'm working with the junit-team to allow such filter specification from the command line: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/647